# Using "Controls" as a folder name in root for asp.net Web Site OR WAP project type

Tags: asp.net

I just wonder if using a folder called "Controls" in the root of either a Web Site Project (yuck) or a WAP project will cause any name collisions in asp.net.

Anyone experience a problem using this particular name for a folder?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it yet?  You will not create any naming collisions unless your *namespaces* collide with types from another assembly.  There is nothing stopping you from calling the folder "Controls" and placing types in the folder in a separate namespace (don't do this though as it is confusing).

And no, in my experience I have yet to see any naming collisions between my types and any other types in other assemblies.  Give your projects good default namespaces and you shouldn't have any issues with extending that namespace and collisions.

Also, this might be of interest to you: [.NET Framework Developer's Guide : Names of Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026.aspx):

> The name chosen for a namespace should
>   indicate the functionality made
>   available by types in the namespace.
>   For example, the System.Net.Sockets
>   namespace contains types that enable
>   developers to use sockets to
>   communicate over networks.
>
> The general format for a namespace
>   name is as follows:
>
> ```
> <Company>.(<Product>|<Technology>)[.<Feature>][.<Subnamespace>]
> ```
>
> For example,
>
> ```
> Microsoft.WindowsMobile.DirectX.
> ```
>
> ***Do prefix namespace names with a
>   company name to prevent namespaces
>   from different companies from having
>   the same name and prefix.***